# Do I have to implement Java Media Framework interfaces?

Tags: java, jmf

I've been reading about Java Media Framework and I am confused about it. For instance, the interfaces Player and Processor. Do I have to implement the `start()` method for these interfaces?

Comment: Your question is very vague. When you implement an interface, the compiler requires all its methods to be implemented. Unless they're adapters.

Comment: So if I call player.start() in a program without implementing this method in the Player interface, my program won't work right?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the methods of the [`Manager`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/apidocs/javax/media/Manager.html#method_summary) API.  It has a number of methods that will supply objects that implement both `Player` and `Processor`.

Comment: createPlayer() ? So if I call start() on one of these objects, the Player will begin to play? I don't have to implement start()? Sorry for being a bit fuzzy on this issue.

Comment: *"So if I call start() on one of these objects, the Player will begin to play?"*  What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Yes it worked! Is this the same case for the DataSource and DataSink creation methods (createDataSource, createDataSink)? I mean if I call getDataOutput on a Processor then I get the output DataSource?